# Why this footer overlaps content above

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a dialog box with a footer, which sometimes overlaps the preceding content, depending on the content. The content has a mixture of float, width, overflow and padding styles.
Below is a distilled version of that issue.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div style="padding:5px">
  <div class="description">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div class="description">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
  <div class="description">CCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
</div>
<div id="tricky" class="broken"></div>
<div style="background: yellow">Footer</div>
```

and the styles:

```
.description {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.broken {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 5px;
}

.fixed {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 5%;
}
```

The expected result would be to have only Footer yellow. For some reason "description" divs are also yellow. If I change class of #tricky from "broken" to "fixed" then it looks as expected. The only difference between these styles is that width is specified either in px or %.
If I remove div #tricky the problem also occurs.

I've made it also available as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgx1qy7r/1/). There is a toggle button to quickly see effect of the different styles.

Please help me understand why these styles makes the footer expand.

Comment: You'll need to give the footer a class to clear the floats. http://jsfiddle.net/pgx1qy7r/2/

Comment: IF you give the containing box a bg colour you can see what's happening to the div with the contained floats. http://jsfiddle.net/pgx1qy7r/3/ To counter act the floats on the container you can use clearfix.

Comment: To all who replied / commented - all your fixes work great, however I would like to understand why the problem occurred in the first place.

Comment: @Aaron - you should have posted this as an answer to give me a chance to accept it

Comment: you could mark the up arrow next to my comment. :o)

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your floats. I like to use clearfix.

Add this to your css:

```
.clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
```

And then give the class 'clearfix' to the parent element of the elements you floated. In this case, the firt , like this:

```
<div class="clearfix" style="padding:5px">
    <div class="description">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    <div class="description">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
    <div class="description">CCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
</div>
```

Clearfix is easy/good practice every time you float something. You can read about it here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `float:left` earlier in your CSS, you need to add some style to your footer

```
<div class="footer" style="background: yellow">Footer</div>
.footer
{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the float:left of description, if you remove it the content above will not be overlapsed. Also to set width:100% and float:left is not very good combination.

Comment: could you elaborate why it is not a good idea ? This is what I'd like to understand.

Comment: float:left is mainly used to put a div on the same row if something is using the whole row how are you gonna put something on this row?